# Processing time for EEA family permit and documents required

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

Am Nigerian non EEA traveling with my Italian husband EEA member not living in the UK, I just applied for the family permit visa, I currently have a schengen visa in my passport valid for 2years, we (myself, my husband and our 6months old son) intend to travel to the UK on the 24th of February 2019, for four days and then Italy for 8days then back to Nigeria, my supporting documents are 
. His Italian passport 
. Our marriage certificate (got married 06/04/2018)
. Our sons Italian passport 
. Flight reservation 
. Hotel reservations
. Some family photos. 
Please are my documents in other or should I add anything other documents?
Please any idea on how long it takes for the visa to be ready? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 Are my documents in order?
According to https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide, you should submit :

- a valid passport
- evidence of your relationship to your EEA family member, for example a marriage certificate, civil partnership certificate, birth certificate or proof that you’ve lived together for 2 years if unmarried
- your family member’s valid passport or national identity card (or a certified copy if you cannot provide the original)
- proof of your dependency if you’re dependent on your EEA family member

Q2 Any idea how long it takes?
Typical processing times appear to be up to 15 days https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y

It’s not 100% clear from your question but I’m assuming you and your family reside in Nigeria.

Comment: Yes we live together in Nigeria